# How to update listView on previous activity from current activity

Tags: java, android, collections, android-activity, updates

I've requirement just like facebook-posts in my application. What i need to do is to open post in full view in next screen and click a like then when i come back i need to display update on basic post list on home page. What is the best approach of doing this. I just want to avoid use of Static Variables. Please help me if anybody have a kind of experience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call the `notifyDatasetChanged()` in your previous activity onResume method.

Comment: You can perform changes you require on the `onResume` method of the `Activity` where you are showing your posts and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Comment: You can write a method to update the listview and call it from OnReasume() for update it.

Comment: yes that's right but how can i update Arraylist from second activity. I don't want to run server call again to update arraylist in home page in onResume. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by calling post Activity with `startActivityForResult()` and refreshing data in `onActivityResult()` method.